# Vk API возвращает пустой массив вложений беседы

Tags: node.js, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Хочу вернуть материалы диалога беседы (фотографии) методом `getHistoryAttachments`. Если диалог с ботом в лс, то все отрабатывает. Если диалог в беседе, то возвращается пустой массив `items`. В настройках беседы боту разрешён доступ к переписке, дана админка. Почему так происходит?

```
import {VK} from 'vk-io';
const vk = new VK({
    token: '*****'
});

(async function initialize() {
    await vk.updates.start().catch(console.error)
}())

vk.updates.on('message_new', async (context)=>{
    if (context.text === 'give') {
        let his = await vk.api.messages.getHistoryAttachments({
            chat_id: context.chatId,
            peer_id: context.peerId,
            media_type: "photo"
        });
        console.log(his.items)
    }
})
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Столкнулся с точно такой же проблемой. Написал в поддержку.

Их ответ:

> У ботов есть доступ к истории сообщений только в диалогах с пользователями и в беседе самого сообщества. Во всех остальных беседах история для бота не сохраняется. Поэтому и метод messages.getHistoryAttachments возвращает пустой список.